# calling a self destructor from inside a method

Tags: c++

I wanted to know if its possible to call a Destructor of a class from its own method.
for instance say I have a class foo created as such

```
foo* f = new foo();
```

now suppose `foo` has a method called `finalize`

```
void foo::finalize()
{
   //do some finalizing code
   //Delete the instance;
}
```

is it possible for finalize to call the destructor of `foo` and recover the memory that was allocated by `new` ? if so how ?

Comment: Warning : Don't confuse calling the destructor and freeing the memory...

Comment: Warning: be sure you never call `finalize()` on a `foo` that wasn't allocated by `new`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `delete this;` to delete the object from within a method

Comment: but with the massive caveat that it's only valid to do so if the object was dynamically allocated. So calling `delete this` in any class that does not enforce dynamic allocation (e.g. through private constructors and a factory method) is a huge code smell.

Comment: Yes. The OP said "say I have a class foo created as such" with a dynamic allocation. But you're right to be explicit. I don't advocate doing this, but it did answer the question :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not so much calling the destructor directly, as calling `delete this` which then calls the destructor. Either way the answer is a very definite YES as this pattern is used extensively in reference counted frameworks such as COM.

Answer (score 1):

Putting `this->~foo();` will call foo's destructor.

So,

```
void foo::finalize()
{
     // do something
     this->~foo();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it won't recover the memory.

Comment: @MarkRansom It won't free the memory allocated by `new`, but it will make it impossible for the client code to call `delete` on it.  This is something you should _never_ do unless you're also using placement new to construct.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, it is the opposite of using placement new or `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct`.